# UILabel Autolayout width trouble

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

So I'm trying to use autolayout for cell content view to get the proper layout. So my problem is that I have a `UILabel` that changes its size with respect to its text and I also have a `UIView` as a background view for this label with rounded corners. So my question is, how to force this `UIView's` width to be 10 points wider than the `UILabel`. I managed to make it the same width but how can I force it always to be a certain length wider?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just add 10 points with the width of UILabel.

Comment: But UILabel width changes dynamically with constraint Width >= than 100px. So how can I add 10 points to it's width?

Comment: you can add it programatically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSLayoutConstraint *widthConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:yourLabel
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                      toItem:yourLabel.superview
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                  multiplier:1.0
                                                                    constant:10]; // <-- this
[yourLabel.superview addConstraint:widthConstraint];
```

Answer (score 0):

An autolayout constraint is nothing but an equation of the form

```
attribute1 == multiplier × attribute2 + constant
```

Note that programatically, you can virtually set any constraint on your views. The interface builder is however a bit limited given that you can relate only certain pairs of `(attribute1,attribute2)` an as you have noticed you may not be able to provide `constant`.

Have a look at 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/NSLayoutConstraint/NSLayoutConstraint.html

Comment: Basically you're right, but layout constraints aren't limited to relationEqual and you can skip the second attribute all together if you'd rather tie it to a constant.